# Outline filter for a jpeg image

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, vtk, vtk.js

I have the following jpg image:
[image]

What king of filter should I use in order to filter the outline (margins only) of this image ?

I have tried this:

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkJPEGReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkJPEGReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(sFile);
    reader->SetDataByteOrderToBigEndian();
    reader->Update();


    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageDataGeometryFilter> geometryfilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageDataGeometryFilter>::New();
    geometryfilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
    geometryfilter->SetOutputTriangles(1);
    geometryfilter->SetThresholdCells(1);
    geometryfilter->Update();
```

Save back to jpg:

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkJpegWriter> writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkJpegWriter>::New();
    writer->SetInputConnection(geometryfilter->GetOutputPort());
    writer->SetFileName(sFile);
    writer->Write();
```

But it doesn't working. I have also tried:

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageDataGeometryFilter> geometryfilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageDataGeometryFilter>::New();
    geometryfilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
    geometryfilter->SetOutputTriangles(1);
    geometryfilter->SetThresholdCells(1);
    geometryfilter->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter> outline = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter>::New();
    outline->SetInputConnection(geometryfilter->GetOutputPort());
    outline->SetGenerateFaces(1);
    outline->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkJpegWriter> writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkJpegWriter>::New();
    writer->SetInputConnection(outline->GetOutputPort());
    writer->SetFileName(sFile);
    writer->Write();
```

Not work that either. Can you help me a little bit ?

Comment: Start by not using a lossy image codec (like jpg). Doing this will allow you to run a trivially simple filter over your source. It's trivially simple because it won't have to deal with approximations introduced by lossy encoding.

Comment: Once this file is loaded in vtkImageDataGeometryFilter, I guess it doesn't matter what kind of filter is used for input data. The question is how to filter this input data in order to get the margins only.

Comment: Make it lossless. Finding edges in a monochrome image is trivial. Finding edges in a grayscale image isn't quite as trivial. Your jpg is going to have fuzzy edges as a result of the lossy compression.

Comment: Could you tell me how to find the edges if that image would be lossless ?

Comment: Is there any vtk filter that can be used to achieve this ?